# Outputing Remove-Item to a log file

Tags: powershell

Scanning a directory for a specific set of files and sorting them by date. Keeping 7 of the LATEST copies of the file regardless of date, and removing the oldest if over 7. I am having a hard time producing a log file showing the deletes since `Remove-Item` has no output.

Below is a copy of my code:

```
$path = "C:\- Deploy to Production -\Previous Deploys\*_*_BOAWeb.rar" #BOA 
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object {-not $_.PsIsContainer}
$keep = 7
if ($files.Count -gt $keep) {
  $files | Sort-Object CreationTime |
    Select-Object -First ($files.Count - $keep) |
    Remove-Item -Force 
}
```

Comment: Use the verbose flag...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off you are over complicating things. Add `-Descending` to your `Sort` command, and then change your `Select` to `-Skip $keep`. It's simpler that way. Then you have options for outputting your deleted files.

```
Remove-Item -Force -Verbose 4>&1 | Add-Content C:\Path\To\DeletedFiles.log
```

or (keeping with your current code above)

```
Select-Object  -First ($files.Count - $keep) |Tee-Object -filepath C:\Path\To\DeletedFiles.log -append
```

The first will output the verbose output of Delete-Item and append it to whatever log file you specify the path for (use `Set-Content` if you want to replace the log instead). The second option will append the `[FileInfo]` objects onto a log that you specify.

**Edit:** As pointed out by Ansgar Wiechers, I had forgotten to to combine my verbose and stdout streams, so `4>&1` was added to the above code to correct that issue.

Comment: Thank you @AnsgarWiechers I always forget verbose is another stream! I'll make sure to fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: I would love to use verbose, but am not running a high enough version of Powershell on this server :(

Comment: I did post a second option, did that not work for you either?